# Algorithm to search for similar lists of integers

Tags: sql, algorithm, sqlite, data-mining, cluster-analysis

I have a SQLite database that contains two tables:

```
Objects:
  object_id int,
  name varchar(50)

Values:
  key char(12),
  value int,
  object_id int
```

As you can see each object contains a list of key-value pairs. This list usually contains between 10 and 60 entries. The combination of (key, object_id) is unique in the values table.

I then get a list of key-value-pairs from the user and want to search the database for the most similar objects. The object provided by the user will in most cases not directly match any of the objects in my database.

Similarity means, that the lists of keys of both objects are almost equal and the values of those keys are similar (in most cases the values won't be equal either). The list can be of variable length.

Consider the following lists:

```
A = { a: 10, b: 20, c: 30 }
B = { a: 11, c: 80, d: 90 }
C = { c: 70, d: 89, e: 40, f: 100 }
D = { c: 65, d: 80, e: 41 }
```

A and B both contain the keys *a* and *c* whereas *b* and *d* are only contained in one of them. So if we only look at the keys the similarity would be 0.5. A and D have only *c* in common, *a*, *b*, *d* and *e* are only contained in one list. So they would not be very similar.

In the next step I have to look for the values of the matching keys. So in the example of A and B, the values of the keys *a* and *c* have to be compared. *a* is pretty similar whereas *c* is not a good match.

Is it possible to do such a search directly with SQLite? If not, what would be the best way / algorithm to do the search? The search should be as fast as possible, but should not consume too much computation power / memory as I'm doing this on a mobile device.

I would very much appreciate any help, links or resources regarding this topic.

Comment: How do you define `similar keys` or `almost equal objects` ?

Comment: The keys themselves are either equal or not. The lists can contain a variable number of key-value pairs, so that some of the keys are in both lists and some are not. The objects are almost equal if most of the keys are contained in both lists and only few are in only one of them. The values of those keys should then be as similar as possible (always integers).

Comment: So `similarity` means that at least K keys are equal ?

Comment: okay, you've defined that `similar` is equivalent to `almost`, now define `almost` please. Some sample close mathces and close non matches would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. I added an example to my question. Is it more clear now?

Comment: It's not clear. How *exactly* should the similarity be computed? Please show examples for all combinations of these objects, or a better description of how to compute it. Do you actually have an algorithm?

Comment: No matter the algorithm, this is at least an NxN operation (really more like NxNxM), and thus likely to be slow, and get markedly slower as more objects are added. Often, difficult problems are due to an upstream architecture decision constraint. Is this key/value model really necessary?

Comment: Not really. I want to search for the _n_ most similar items. I'm just reading about locality-sensitive hashing, maybe this would be a solution to my problem? This way I would not have to store each key-value-pair but just one hash to compare the matching values and another to compare the keys.

Answer (score 1):

if i get it correctly, you want to compare all records with a fixed set of records from user input (let's say it is a table with the same structure as `Values`) => **O(n*m<sub>1</sub>*m<sub>2</sub>)** *(where n=no. of objects, n*m<sub>1</sub>=no. of records in Values, m<sub>2</sub>=keys in user input)* - basically O(n) if m<sub>1, 2</sub> are constant factors:

```
select
  v1.object_id,
  count(distinct v1.key) cnt_obj_keys,
  count(distinct v2.key) cnt_usr_keys, --replace with a constant from outside code
  count(case
          when v1.key = v2.key
          then 1
        end) cnt_similar_keys,
  count(case
          when v1.key = v2.key and v1.value = v2.value
          then 1
        end) cnt_similar_values
from values v1
cross join values_from_user v2
group by v1.object_id
;
```

then you just need to use a formula for each object, i.e. **O(n)**, to compute the unspecified index used to sort the objects and fetch the first `x` of them - e.g.:

```
order by
  cnt_similar_keys / (cnt_obj_keys + cnt_usr_keys - cnt_similar_keys),
  cnt_similar_values / cnt_similar_keys
```